# Is [templates] worth cleaning up?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki states that [templates](/questions/tagged/templates) has multiple uses, which gives off a serious meta-tag smell:

> The templates tag is used in multiple contexts: generic programming (especially C++), and data/document generation using template engines.

Is this really a useful tag? It feels like these questions should use a more specific tag - for example, [generics](/questions/tagged/generics) where it makes sense.

Unfortunately it's a really old tag, so it is problematic to remove—there almost 20k questions tagged with it. Is it worth attempting to clean up, or is this essentially a 'grandfathered' tag?

If the consensus is to allow this tag to remain, then perhaps it should be prevented from being used in new questions?

Comment: Doing a search for both C++ and Templates should yield about a 99% confidence level in the search results.

Comment: what about code generation? what tag should we use for that?

Comment: My immediate reaction is that the work would be massive and the payoff fairly minimal.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create some disambiguating ones first, such as [c++-templates](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-templates) and then there are zillions of possibilities after that: [python-templates](/questions/tagged/python-templates), [wordpress-templates](/questions/tagged/wordpress-templates) etc.

Failing that, you could declare that [templates](/questions/tagged/templates) is ONLY for C++ templates and remove it from all the other questions. I doubt that would work over the long term.

Comment: Would be a helluva lot of retagging. Think about all the +2 rep that could be gained...

Comment: Probably synonyming c++-templates and templates as a first step, then flat out removing it from the others or creating specific *-templates tags question by question. Yeah, a lot of work.

Comment: Then we could move on to 'macro' (different meaning in C and VBA), 'assembly' (low level programming vs. .NET framework distributable). Where will it end?

Answer (score 2):

Loosely speaking, Templates are for C++ as Generics are for Java.

Templates are such an integral part of C++ (and a difficult area so expect lots of questions) that it would be idiosyncratic to refer to them as anything else.

So Templates must stay as a tag.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the wiki also includes template engines.

Comment: Indeed, my answer is somewhat geared towards "Yes we should keep this tag: here is one compelling reason. No doubt there are others."